# How to make font bold in java dialogue box?

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " " + company1 + 
            " Has Higher A Market Value\nThan " + company2,
                "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

I want to make company1 and company2 appear bold in the dialogue box. I tried using html formatting but (I suppose) obviously that did not work.

Any clues or hints?

TIA!

Answer (score 28):

Use `HTML`

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html> <b> Has </b>Higher A Market Value</html> ");
```

If your default font doesn't support it then you can specify it like

```
 String msg = "<html>This is how to get:<ul><li><i>italics</i> and "
        + "<li><b>bold</b> and "
        + "<li><u>underlined</u>...</ul></html>";
        JLabel label = new JLabel(msg);
        label.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, label);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Does not seem to work (I am not very experienced with java formatting).

Comment: Would it be like this? JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html> <b> " + company2 + </b></html>. Do I need to import a class to make this work? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Yes,  bold effect will also depend on  font you are using.

Comment: Very nice answer, @Jigar, though I personally think that using "sans-serif" for the font looks better.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't realise that HTML could be used in the showMessageDialog. Thank you for educating me! :)