# Setting font in JOptionPane without using HTML

Tags: java, swing, fonts, joptionpane

I tried this: [Code Zip](http://ndt.yw.lt/files/1063044/ErrorDialog.zip)

Sorry for the inconvenience but I could not attach the whole code (though it's not too big) and could not provide .java extension link so you have to get the zip and it open in html where code is with syntax highlighting.

I read these:

- [Java GUI - JOptionPane/JDialog customization issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785580/java-gui-joptionpane-jdialog-customization-issue)
- [How to make font bold in java dialogue box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769076/how-to-make-font-bold-in-java-dialogue-box)

But I don't want to use HTML.

### Code

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    JFrame jf;
    jf = new JFrame();
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jf.setBounds(100, 100, 530, 350);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    jp.setFont(new Font("Algerian", Font.ITALIC, 11));
    jf.add(jp);
    String message = "Hello World!”;
    JOptionPane jop;
    jop = new JOptionPane();
    Object[] obj = { UIManager.put("Panel.font",new Font("Algerian", Font.ITALIC, 11)) , message };
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jp,obj,"Dialog",JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
  }
```

Comment: Your post could use some formatting improvements, as well as your odd method of attaching code. Please copy and paste your relevant code.

Comment: *"but I could not attach the whole code (though its not too big)"*  The forum will allow 700+ lines of code, which yes, *is too big.*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: i think i got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This MCVE shows one label in 3 option panes with 3 different variants of the same (default) font.  It is simply a matter of passing the option pane a component that has the font set, as opposed to a string or a generic object.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FontInOptionPane {

    FontInOptionPane() {
        JLabel l = new JLabel();
        Font f = l.getFont();
        l.setText(f.toString());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l);

        f = f.deriveFont(Font.ITALIC);
        l.setText(f.toString());
        l.setFont(f);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l);

        f = f.deriveFont(50f);
        l.setText(f.toString());
        l.setFont(f);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FontInOptionPane();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java Swing, you globally set your `JOptionPane` font by using the following code lines:

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
UIManager.put("OptionPane.buttonFont", new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
```

This works like a charm.